# Interactivity with bars in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I made a litte h-bar example.
What I want is to be able to resize any of the bar with the mouse.
I select one by focusing on
I want to begin resizing when I create a mouse-down even and ending resizing by a mouse-up event.
Actually, It works but only for the first bar and I dont see the bar resizing while I mve the mouse but only when I make amouse-up.
I have got a fiddle at jsfiddle.net/Yves_49/jjj40cop/

This is my code

```
function draw_2() {

var valueMax = 5;
var tab_val = new Array();
for (currentLine = 0; currentLine < 10; currentLine++) {
    var tab_temp = new Array();
    tab_temp['name'] = "name_" + currentLine;
    tab_temp['value'] = Math.round(Math.random() * valueMax * 10) / 10;
    tab_val[currentLine] = tab_temp;
    tab_temp.length = 0;
}

d3.select("body").selectAll("div.h-bar")
    .data(tab_val)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "h-bar")
    .append("span");

d3.select("body").selectAll("div.h-bar")
    .data(tab_val)
    .attr("class", "h-bar")
    .style("width", function(d) {
        return (d.value * 100) + "px";
    })
    .style("background-color", function(d) {
        return "rgb(" + (200 - Math.round(200 * d.value / valueMax)) + "," + (200 - Math.round(200 * d.value / valueMax)) + ",256 )";
    })
    .select("span")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });

d3.select("body").select(".h-bar")
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        d3.select(this)
            .style("background-color", function() {
                return "rgb(256,0,0)";
            })
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
            .style("background-color", function(d) {
                return "rgb(" + (200 - Math.round(200 * d.value / valueMax)) + "," + (200 - Math.round(200 * d.value / valueMax)) + ",256 )";
            })
    });

d3.select("body")
    .on("mouseup", function() {
        d3.select(this)
            .select(".h-bar")
            .style("width", function() {
                return (d3.mouse(this)[0]) + "px";
            })
            .style("background-color", function() {
                return "rgb(0,256,0)";
            })
            .select("span")
            .text(function(d) {
                return (Math.round(d3.mouse(this)[0] / 10) / 10);
            });
    });
```

Yves

Answer (score 2):

Solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/wtmsmwxk/1/

There are several points I have corrected:

- `.select(".h-bar")`selects only the first item, so it explains why only your first bar could ever move. You need to use `selectAll` instead.
- you need to register a `mousedown` event on each bar, and a `mouseup` and `mousemove`events for the whole container, since you should assume the mouse can move out of the bar.
- you need to remember which bar is being dragged: keep a reference to the selection at the mousedown time. This is the job of the `dragging` variable (which I set to undefined if no dragging is occurring).
- to update the width of the bar continuously, the width updating function should be in the mousemove, not mouseup.

Main new lines:

```
var dragging = undefined;
d3.select("body").selectAll(".h-bar")
.on("mousedown", function() {dragging = d3.select(this)});

d3.select("body")
.on("mouseup", function() {dragging=undefined})
.on("mousemove", function() {
  if (!dragging) return;
  dragging
    .style("width", function() { ...})
 }
```